# WCF can't get the MaxReceivedMessageSize to increase

Tags: wcf, binding

First, the app.config is basically empty.  Everything is done in code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I get this error.
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

```
 m_Host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(Service.SalesMonitorService), 
                new Uri(
                    String.Format(
                        "http://{0}:{1}/SalesMonitorService/Version{2}", 
                        System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName, 
                        port, 
                        ver)));
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        **binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647**;
        //maxBufferSize="567890" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
        // maxReceivedMessageSize="567890"
        //binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        //binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;

        //binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        //binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        //binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        //binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        //binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

        //binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message;
        m_Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(ISalesMonitorService),
            binding,
            ""
            );

        ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle;
        throttle = m_Host.Description.Behaviors.
                          Find<ServiceThrottlingBehavior>();
        if (throttle == null)
        {
            throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
            throttle.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
            throttle.MaxConcurrentSessions = 100;

            m_Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);
        }

        try
        {
            m_Host.Open();
        }
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Both client and server has their own quota so your code should apply only if client sends large amount of data to the service but if the service return large amount of data to the client using WCF it will use default 65KB limit unless you reconfigure client as well.

Comment: I get this when I pass data from the server to the client.  I am using the wcftestclient for testing.  I am not sure how to configure that.

Comment: I would be inclined to un-comment the *MaxBufferSize* etc sizes also consider the IIS configuration for the maximum size of data uploads *maxAllowedContentLength* or *maxRequestLength* (depending on IIS version) in your web.config. *updated* Ah, you said app.config so perhaps irrelevant...